# Google calendar API and HTTP Headers

Tags: swift, oauth, http-headers, google-calendar-api

I am not able to get the Google Calendar framework to compile in my iOS project, so I decided to build the requests manually after getting my Oauth token from Google SignIn's framework.

I have been running into a wall for the past day.  The following doesn't seem to want to provide me access, I keep getting a 403 error.

```
func requestEvents() {
    let email = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.profile.email.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    let token = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.accessToken
    let urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/\(email!)/events?key=CalendarHelper.apiKey

    let url = NSURL(urlString)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url) 
    request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization") 
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession() 
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, request, error in
    print(NSJSONSerialization.jsonobjectwithdata(data, options: .PrettyPrinted))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After spending an entire day trying to figure this out I finally found the answer.

I used the Google API explorer to make a request for my own calendar information and then inspected the header sent with that request.  In the Google generated request the auth header looks like this:

authroziation : "Bearer [tokenString]"

After I was able to get out from under my deadline I found this page in the Oauth specification.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2